# openoffice transfromed decimal separator for an xlsx file in server machine

Tags: linux, openoffice, xlsx

i try to configure openoffice in linux server to use comma as decimal separator,i search and i found that have a relation with regional parametre so i configure etc/locales.conf to use french as default language but i still have the same problem (the file i use is an xlsx  6 300,20£ is transformed on 6,300.20£):

```
[default]
date format = %b %e %Y %I:%M:%S:%z%p
        LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
        LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
        LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8


        [fr_FR]
date format = %b %e %Y %I:%M:%S:%z%p
language = fr_french
charset = UTF-8
```

is there an other solution to fix this problem

Comment: I assume you also need to adjust the OpenOffice user profile settings. Did you try this already?

Comment: no i didn't adjust the OpenOffice user profile settings,how can i do it because i'm in linux server ans i can acces just with putty

Answer (score 0):

If OpenOffice.org isn't reading your /etc/locales.conf as you want it to, you could also try changing the locale on the command line before running OOO. Like this:

```
export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8; soffice -calc;
```

Comment: the command doesn't work                                                     [root@root ~]# export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8; soffice -calc;
-bash: [root@root : commande introuvable

Comment: How do you usually start openoffice? Just add `export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8;` before that. I thought that `soffice -calc` would start up OpenOffice Calc.